# CausalImpact - Choose the predictor time series as the shifted series

Tags: time-series, rare-events

I asked this at the contributor's [repo](https://github.com/google/CausalImpact), but did not get any answers (seems somehow dead). It is about CausalImpact, to measure the impact of an event.

I am interested in the CausalImpact to analyse the impact of an event on a time series.

Now, it the serious challenge to find a proper Control Series, I think. But unfortunately in my case this might be a problem. So I came to the following idea.

What about using the shifted time series for your response? If I have click rates for the last 3 years and what to analyse the impact of my event, I think I could use the same Series shifted by let's say 1 year. This underlies the assumption that over a year for eg a specific month my Response behaves similar to last years'month. So I can use the shifted series to see if the event has an impact for this year's month?

This seems a very easy idea, but is not mentioned especially in this nice video.

Maybe I oversee some statistical consequences?

Any one who has an idea?

Comment: So you want to use last year as your control for causal impact? You don't need a control series for causal impact and I think what you are saying would be roughly equivalent to that.

Comment: Yes, I think this is intuitive and don't know why this is not mentioned anywhere. So I feel this might not be good? But I think you can safe say (and assume) that last year is my "normal" year, and use it as a control?